# switch http and https without php notices errors

Tags: php, http, https, error-log, notice

I use http on some pages and https on others.

At the top of each page I tell which I want.
Sometimes I get these notices in the error log and want to avoid them:

[20-Nov-2016 00:21:39 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in .....

[20-Nov-2016 03:37:43 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTPS in .....

These are the php codes I have on top of each page:

```
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
    {
            $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $good_url = "http://" . $host . $request_uri;

            header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
            header( "Location: $good_url" );
            exit;
    }

    if  ( !$_SERVER['HTTPS'] )
    {
            $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $good_url = "https://" . $host . $request_uri;

            header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
            header( "Location: $good_url" );
            exit;
    }
```

Comment: You should use `array_key_exists()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: `if (array_key_exists('HTTPS', $_SERVER)) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I will try that.

Comment: If it works, please tell me so that I can provide you with an acceptable answer.